# Google Translate shows blank screen in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, google-translate, google-translator-toolkit

Google Translator has stopped working in Chrome 85.0.4183 (also in Canary, Opera, Edge).
For example, after pressing "Translate" button at https://colnect.com/en/collectors/collector/teleawe
it shows "`about:blank#blocked`". The Translate button itself has "`about:invalid#zClosurez`" link.

The xhr request to https://translate.googleapis.com/translate_a/t?anno=... is shown as cancelled in devtool console.
Also here is notice about cross-site cookies affected to https://translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleSectionalElementInit&ug=section&hl=en request.

The same link works well in Firefox.

Also https://codepen.io/paul/pen/ZZzEpQ sample works, it's without callback but also shows the translation service still working.

Could you please help me how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem.

I fix it with the following code :

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        setTimeout( function() {
            $(".goog-te-gadget-link").click(function(){
                $(this).attr('href', 'javascript:;');
            });
        }, 2000);
    });
```

If you have a better solution, I'll take it :)

Regards

Comment: thank you, it works and let's looking for better solution together

Answer (score 0):

I had same few days ago and fixed by evt.preventDefault(). Just add this to google-translate link. After this translate will work by clicking at link

```html
somePlaceWithThsProblem.$el.on('click', '.goog-te-gadget-link', (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();
});
```