# Google Translate has stopped working on Chrome, Safari and Opera (still works on Firefox)

Tags: javascript, php, html

Some time ago the Google section translate function has stopped working on most browsers (excluding Firefox), resulting in blank page with "about:blank#blocked" address when someone click on TRANSLATE link under the post (example post, does not need to log in or register to use translate feature: https://www.elvikom.pl/hp-probook-6560b-cure-uma-hr-hpb-mv-mb-v1-sam-sie-uruchamia-t65407.html).

I found that piece of code on stackoverflow: [Google Translate shows blank screen in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64168828/google-translate-shows-blank-screen-in-chrome) but I do not know where to place it exactly. Tried to add it right before closing `</head>` tag as well as right after opening `<body>` tag but cannot get this code working.

My code right after opening `<body>` tag (still works on Firefox):

```
<script>
function googleSectionalElementInit() {
  new google.translate.SectionalElement({
    sectionalNodeClassName: 'goog-trans-section',
    controlNodeClassName: 'goog-trans-control',
    background: '#f4fa58'
  }, 'google_sectional_element');
}
</script>
<!-- IF S_USER_LANG eq 'pl' -->
<script src="//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleSectionalElementInit&ug=section&hl=pl"></script>
<!-- ELSEIF S_USER_LANG eq 'ru' -->
<script src="//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleSectionalElementInit&ug=section&hl=ru"></script>
<!-- ELSEIF S_USER_LANG eq 'en' -->
<script src="//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleSectionalElementInit&ug=section&hl=en"></script>
<!-- ELSEIF S_USER_LANG eq 'sl' -->
<script src="//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleSectionalElementInit&ug=section&hl=sl"></script>
<!-- ELSEIF S_USER_LANG eq 'de' -->
<script src="//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleSectionalElementInit&ug=section&hl=de"></script>
<!-- ELSEIF S_USER_LANG eq 'it' -->
<script src="//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleSectionalElementInit&ug=section&hl=it"></script>
<!-- ENDIF -->
```

And my template (html) code:

```
<div class="goog-trans-section">{postrow.MESSAGE}<br /><br /><a href="javascript:void(0);"><span class="goog-trans-control"></span></a></div>
```

Comment: And what does the JS console say? Note that most web requests get redirected to "//hypen-ated-fqdn.translate.goog/…" meanwhile; so might well impair the script handling.

Comment: Sorry, just a few moments ago I have fixed this. Below is my answer with the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a moment after I have posted my question, I've tried to put that suggested code inside the `function googleSectionalElementInit()` function. So my current code right after opening `<body>` tag looks like that:

```
<script>
function googleSectionalElementInit() {
  new google.translate.SectionalElement({
    sectionalNodeClassName: 'goog-trans-section',
    controlNodeClassName: 'goog-trans-control',
    background: '#f4fa58'
  }, 'google_sectional_element');
 $(document).ready(function(){
  setTimeout( function() {
   $(".goog-te-gadget-link").click(function(){
    $(this).attr('href', 'javascript:;');
   });
  }, 2000);
 });
}
</script>
<!-- IF S_USER_LANG eq 'pl' -->
<script src="//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleSectionalElementInit&ug=section&hl=pl"></script>
<!-- ELSEIF S_USER_LANG eq 'ru' -->
<script src="//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleSectionalElementInit&ug=section&hl=ru"></script>
<!-- ELSEIF S_USER_LANG eq 'en' -->
<script src="//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleSectionalElementInit&ug=section&hl=en"></script>
<!-- ELSEIF S_USER_LANG eq 'sl' -->
<script src="//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleSectionalElementInit&ug=section&hl=sl"></script>
<!-- ELSEIF S_USER_LANG eq 'de' -->
<script src="//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleSectionalElementInit&ug=section&hl=de"></script>
<!-- ELSEIF S_USER_LANG eq 'it' -->
<script src="//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleSectionalElementInit&ug=section&hl=it"></script>
<!-- ENDIF -->
```

And now the translate function works perfectly fine on Chrome, Opera and Safari :)