# google.translate.SectionalElement is not a constructor

Tags: google-translate

Did Google remove `google.translate.SectionalElement`?

Сode like below stopped working:

```js
<script>
function googleSectionalElementInit() {
    new google.translate.SectionalElement({
        sectionalNodeClassName: 'can-translate',
        controlNodeClassName: 'translation-control',
    }, 'google_sectional_element');
}
</script>
<script src="https://translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleSectionalElementInit"></script>
```

Maybe there was some announcement that they stopped supporting it?

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69532270/google-translate-has-stopped-working-on-chrome-safari-and-opera-still-works-on

Comment: This time it doesn't work in all browsers. Maybe relation is here https://support.google.com/answer/9464390